# How to create and Deploy a Mono ASP.NET web project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

So the web server i am using right now is a Apache web server which runs ASP.Net on mono but i can't seem to get a project up and running on the mono ASP.Net server as it all ways just lists the directories within the folder

I tried creating a ASP.Net project uploaded it didn't work
I tried creating a MVC project and uploading it, also did not work
I tried creating a project on a .net framework 4 and uploaded it but still no luck

I've run of out of ideas how to get this to work, is there i special way i should be compiling the project? or is there a specfic version of .net i should use, as the mono ASP.NET version says 4

Answer (score 1):

Mono is a linux based runtime like the .NET framework is a windows based runtime. You don't have "mono ASP.NET web projects" - you have "ASP.NET web projects" that run on .net framework in windows or mono (maybe) in linux.

What I'd actually recommend you do is create a .net core site if this is a new project; microsoft provide core for windows and linux so it should be easier to get started developing something that compiles and runs on windows, and then is either transported compiled to linux or recompiled there.

Note that your apache (if you're dead set on using that) will probably need to be [configured as a proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1) so that it forwards requests through to Kestrel, which is hosting your app. Apache doesn't natively understand .NET anything, and will just see a .NET application as a bunch of folders and files

Comment: i can only agree - dump mono and use asp.netcore

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer How do i compile a project on Linux runtime in visual studio?

Comment: when a dotnet library is compiled, it creates a dll file. this file is intermediate code, you can run from any system with the correct runtime. its like `dotnet xxx.dll`